# ntldr, boot.ini, etc not found on Windows XP SP 2 running on VMware

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, vmware

So I am reading a book on how to pass the A+ certification and was following along with the book when I noticed that my version of Windows, Windows XP - Service Pack 2 - Home Edition made for Dell products, does not have some of the critical boot files the author mentions in the book. These files are:

- ntldr
- boot.ini
- ntdetect.com

Everything works really well though, so I am not sure what is going on. I was hoping some expert here could help me out without having to join vmware forums and/or Microsoft Windows forums.

Thank-you for reading this.

Comment: First mandatory step would be to update to SP3 before we can help you.

Comment: hehe - I  want SP2 so that I can pen-test this incredibly vulnerable version of Windows though.

Comment: Well those files do exist

Comment: I searched the entire computer, including hidden files, with the search tool and did not find them. Thanks for the clue though. ;)

Comment: Hint: these are 'system' files. While not visible they are not necessarily 'hidden'. Do you have the option to 'view hidden/system' files in your explorer folder options unchecked?

Comment: Hi, last I checked this option was toggled in the explorer folder options window. I found these files on another version of XP on a different computer. Well the `ntldr` file at least. I am thinking that this operating system disc I have, which is made for Dell computers, may use different files to start the operating system (OS). 0_o Thanks again for chiming in.

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes, this option to show hidden files is in fact toggled in the view pane of the `Folder Options` dialogue window in explorer. :D

Comment: I just found what I was missing @Ramhound @txtechhelp ! :D! I had toggled the `Show hidden files and folders` radio button but I forgot to uncheck `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` Now I see all the files I was looking for. :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

So to see these system files (ntldr, boot.ini, ntdetect.com) 
Click:

- Start
- My Computer
- C: drive (or wherever your bootable partition is)

Then click:

- Tools
- Folder Options
- View

In the View pane toggle the `Show hidden files and folders` radio button. Then, scroll down further in the same View pane and uncheck the `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` option. Then click the Apply and OK buttons.

The files will appear in the Windows Explorer program as greyed out files. I am not sure how to edit these or anything.